# Calculate a point offset along a relative diagonal

Tags: java, geometry, coordinates

I have a diagonal line / plane (A, B), for which I have an offset point (C).
I now need to move this point (C) along the same plane as the diagonal line, keeping the same offset distance, to a percentage of the line A-B.

[image]

This is probably quite "simple", however I can't seem to get my head around the maths involved.  I have googled alot for this but have not found the answer which will get what I am needing.

Help to translate the "pure" maths formula into a code form would be greatly appreciated also as I am (obviously) not a maths oriented person.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
public static Point moveInDirection(Point a, Point b, Point c,  double ratio) {
    return new Point(
            (int) Math.round(c.x + (b.x - a.x) * ratio),
            (int) Math.round(c.y + (b.y - a.y) * ratio));
}
```

Comment: Ok, after more testing, this solution will move the point by the ratio.  So, if I as for 40%, it will move it BY 40% of the original line and not to the offset position of 40% along the line.  How can I move it to be at the, say, 40% offset position ?